# jQuery, Ajax, PHP two checkboxes

Tags: php, html, ajax, jquery

I can't get acces to input checkbox_material. It's something wrong with my code. Please help me. My textarea workes fint, but checkbox_material never begin set. Please help me to figure out what the problem is.

**My Form:**

```
<div class="form_style">
<div id="checkbox_content"></div>
   <input type="checkbox" value="1" alt="Checkbox" name="checkbox_material[]">One
   <input type="checkbox" value="2" alt="Checkbox" name="checkbox_material[]">Two<br>
   <textarea id="materialMessage" rows="5" cols="45" name="material_message"></textarea<br>
   <button id="materialSubmit">Add record</button>
</div>
```

**Javascript:**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#materialSubmit").click(function (e) { 
        e.preventDefault();
        if($("#materialMessage").val() === "") {
            alert("Please enter some text!");
            return false;
        }


    var query_string = '';
    $("input[@type='checkbox'][@name='checkbox_material']").each(function() {
        if (this.checked) {
            query_string += "&checkbox_material[]=" + this.value;
        }
    }); 

    if(query_string.length == 0) {
        alert("Please enter some HELLO!");
        return false;
    }

    alert("Hej");
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "material.php",
        data: "id=1" + query_string,
        success:function(t) {
            $("div#checkbox_content").empty().append(t);
        },
        error:function() {
            $("div#checkbox_content").append("An error occured during processing");
        }
    });




    var myData = "material_message="+ $("#materialMessage").val(); 
    jQuery.ajax({
      type: "POST",         
      url: "material.php",  
      dataType:"text",      
      data:myData,          
      success:function(response) {
        $("#materialResponds").append(response);
        $("#materialMessage").val(''); 
      },
      error:function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
        alert(thrownError); //throw any errors
      }
    });
  });
```

**PHP:**

```
if (isset($_POST['checkbox_material'])) 
{
   print_r($_POST['checkbox_material']); 
}
```

Comment: What version of jQuery are you using? `@attr` selectors were deprecated in 1.2 and removed in 1.3.

Comment: have you tried put numbers in the name of the checkboxes? like name="checkbox_material[0]" name="checkbox_material[1]" and so on?

Answer (score 1):

The brackets are part of the name:

```
var query_string = '';
$("input[name='checkbox_material[]']").each(function() {
    if (this.checked) {
        query_string += "&checkbox_material[]=" + this.value;
    }
});
```